# chapterbib or bibunit with ABNTEX not working

Tags: bibliographies, incompatibility, multibib, chapterbib

I'm writing a thesis using abntex class and I wish I could print references after each part (the thesis has 3 parts), and at the end, after the conclusion I wish I could print all the references that were not cited before in the thesis.

Someone knows how to make the multiple bibliographies works in abntex?**

Code:
\documentclass[fonte, openright,
oneside,a4paper,
sumario = tradicional,
Brazil, french, spanish,
english]{abntex2}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,
right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\include{usualpack} % usual packages

\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{apalike}

\usepackage{chapterbib}

\include{sig} % list of symbol in abntex

% ---
% CONFIGURAÇÕES DE PACOTES
% ---

% ---
% Configurações do pacote backref
% Usado sem a opção hyperpageref de backref
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
\ifcase #1 %
Nenhuma citação no texto.%
\or
Citado na página #2.%
\else
Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
\fi }%

\title{Feasibility of Wind Energy Projects in Brazil using Real Options Theory: Strategy and expansion of the Free Electricity Market}

\data{December 2020}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\include{intro}
\include{review}
\include{valuation}
\include{options}

\part{References}

\bibliography{librarytest}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}

**I've made a minimal example ate overleaf, with all files**
https://www.overleaf.com/3428159342jbwjcqrqhfkr

ADDITION: With the suggestion of Daleif it the multiple bibliographies appears but I've experience new errors: citations with a list of references are not printed and there are many errors at the bbl file that a I cannot fix such as the ones in the pics.

```
[![error memoir bf][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R87ns.png
```

Comment: (1) welcome to the site. (2) please read the chapterbib manual, on page 2 it states that each chapter should either be in a separate file included via `\include` or enclosed in the `cbunit` env, and the included file or `cbunit` chunk should include the `\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}` part. You don't do this here, and thus it does not work.

Comment: Additionally (3) It is better to provide self contained data, here you are refering to data we do not have access to so your example cannot be tested as is. (we have neither `review.tex`, `valuation.tex` or `library.bib`. (4) Note that view a few exceptions the `hyperref` package should be the last package loaded as it has to change a lot of other packages.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and for the help! Here I've made a minimal example that contains what I had as a problem. Your sugestions reallly worked to print multiple references but now I have new problems: wherever I have a list of references \cite{article1,article2} the program is not running. and there are another erros that you can see compiling this file at overleaf:  https://www.overleaf.com/3428159342jbwjcqrqhfkr

Comment: Don't just ignore the errors you get when you compile in overleaf. The file in overleaf does not even compile if you replace the body (the stuff between `\begin/end{document}  `; tip: latex ignores everything after `\end{document}` very useful for debugging) of the document by `hello world`

Comment: I've alredy detected that the error is related to every citation that include more than one article, like this: \cite{shimbar2017modified, Espinoza2014}. I just don't know why this error is happening, because abntex2cite accepts this kind of citation lists. the error message is in the picture and also included at the overleaf project.

Comment: If you replace the body with just `hello`, out comment all packages and your backref macro redefinitions then add the package step by step one will notice that there are some packages here that seems to conflict each other.

Comment: hmm, might be the `sig` file (which you should `\input` not `\include`.  That at least gets of some of the errors. I might consider starting over and not ignoring errors in overleaf

Comment: Also read section 7 of the chapterbib manual. Consider if you want both chapter and overall bibliography